# Use same scale for iPhone X as iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, iphone-x, launchimage

Initially the app was developed for iPhone 5. Later there was a problem with iPhone 6, 6+, scale was low. The solution was to set launch image as it is shown on the screenshot.

[image]

The names and sizes:

**Default-568h@2x.png - 640x1136**

**Default@2x.png - 640x960**

But when you use iPhone X, black lines appear at the top and the bottom. If launch image **1125x2436** is done specially for iPhone X, black lines disappear, but scale is low. Is it possible to make the same scale for iPhone X?

Comment: Use launchScreen.storyboard instead of images. One layout for all iPhones. Easy.

Comment: @AndreyOshev it sets low scale by the way :(

Comment: @AndreyOshev can you explain me how to achieve this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Открываешь сториборд, если просто черный экран, то просто меняешь фон и вместо лаунизображения используешь этот сторибор. Будет все нативно без ресайза. Красиво.

Comment: @AndreyOshev получается разный скейл на 5, 6, Х айфонах. А смысл в том, чтобы было все крупно везде как на 5 айфоне

Comment: Ну так тогда просто правильно констрейнты раскидай и будет везде большое.

Comment: @AndreyOshev вот хоть убей не могу понять как сделать. Вообще не понимаю причину такого поведения launchimage & launchscreen. Если можешь распиши пожалуйста конкретнее. Если не затруднит конечно

Comment: t.me/andrey_oshev

Comment: @AndreyOshev I have an same issue and i am using launch images. if i  will use launch screen storyboard than these black lines are disappear in iPhone X..? And i am not using constraints as well.